# Gracefully Handling 401 Not Authorized with Angularjs $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, angularjs-http

I am currently working on an problem with a login page for an AngularJS app.  The login page uses the `$http` service to submit the username and password using Basic authentication (`Authorization: Basic (username and password in base 64)`) to a Web service that may or may not be running on the same server that the webapp is hosted on.  If authentication succeeds, the server returns a response with status 200 OK; otherwise, it returns a 401 Not Authorized.  We have an error function to gracefully handle this error condition, but before it is even called, the browser by default shows a modal dialog for the user to enter his or her username and password.  How can I prevent this?

I've looked at several sources, including the W3 standards for XHR.send(), for help, and my findings show that in Firefox and Chrome, the browser dialog pops up after a 401 response to an XHR call when all of the following are true:

1) The request is "same-origin" (which it is in the cases where the web service is running on the same server that serves the webapp)

2) The response includes the header `WWW-Authenticate: Basic [some realm]` or `WWW-Authenticate: Digest [some realm]` (our web service returns the former)

3) The request was not made by specifically setting a username and password in the XHR object whose `send()` method was called.

I found a test site (which SO won't let me link to) that exhibits the desired behavior for 401 responses (no modal login box).  It meets the first two conditions but avoids meeting the third, apparently because it sets the XHR object's username and password by sending them as arguments #4 and 5 to its `open()` function.  I'm not sure if there's any other way to set these properties of the XHR object, since I can't even find them by inspecting the XHR object in a browser's JavaScript debugger.

The problem is that our site's login service doesn't itself call `XmlHttpRequest.open()` to pass the username and password; instead, it creates the Authorization header itself and passes it in the headers collection of a params object to `$http`.  By inspecting the source of angular.js, I found that $http then proceeds to call `open()` with only three parameters.

Does Angular provide a way to have `$http` call the 5-parameter overload of open(), or otherwise prevent this login dialog from showing up?  If not, I can only think of a few workarounds:

1) Somehow decorate `$http` to enforce calling the 5-parameter overload of `open()` if a username and password are provided

2) Somehow use `$httpBackend` to achieve the same as #1 (though the documentation discourages developers from using `$httpBackend` so I'm not sure if this is a good idea or even possible)

3) Ignore `$http` and have my login service create and send the XHR itself

4) Alter the server so it doesn't return the `WWW-Authenticate: Basic` header (least desirable)

Is there a well-known or "right" way to work around this problem?

Comment: doesn't look like there is any way to call  the 5 parameter `XmlHttpRequest.open()` with the $http service https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/httpBackend.js#L51

Answer (score 0):

The issues you are facing is due to the first reason you have specified

1) The request is "same-origin" (which it is in the cases where the web service is running on the same server that serves the webapp).

**solution**

Either add access-control-allow-origin header to your backend service in order to acccept calls from different origin.

**or**

if you are in development phase and later your frontend and service are anyway going to be in same origin,then use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en extension ,

this will allow you to override chrome cross origin policy (this is just for development,its a workaround).

**or**

Open chrome with web security disabled by opening chrome from command prompt

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```